# CRA - Dynamic redux-thunk's AppState type fails as "unknown"

Tags: typescript, redux, create-react-app, next.js

I'm moving a NextJS project to Create-React-App. In the later, the dynamic type of the AppState throws as "unknown".

Note that both the projects have the same versions of :

- Typescript: `3.5.3`
- React: `16.9.0`
- Redux, Redux-Thunk, React-Redux

Here's how I create the store and the types:

```js
export function makeStore(initialState: any) {
  const store = createStore(
    combinedReducers,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(thunk as ThunkMiddleware<ReturnType<typeof combinedReducers>, AnyAction>)
    )
  );

  return store;
}

// This type is needed so Store.dispatch is from redux-thunk
export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>;


export type AppState = ReturnType<AppStore['getState']>;
```

Now, importing some data into a component, I have these errors **in CRA app only**:
[image]
The error:
[image]

To my understanding, the IDE(VSCode) gets the type fine, yet Typescript is saying it's *unknown* and fails to compile. I have no idea what to do with that.
Where should I look at to fix this issue?